# Undefined property: DOMDocument::$documentElement in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php-7, php-7.2, dom

> Notice: Undefined property: DOMDocument::$documentElement in
>   /var/www/html/projectnenny/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php on
>   line 148
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   Magento\Framework\Config\Dom::_mergeNode() must be an instance of
>   DOMElement, null given, called in
>   /var/www/html/projectnenny/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php on
>   line 148 and defined in
>   /var/www/html/projectnenny/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php:164
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/html/projectnenny/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php(148):
>   Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->_mergeNode(NULL, '') #1
>   /var/www/html/projectnenny/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Reader/Filesystem.php(151):
>   Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->merge('_readFiles(Object(Magento\Framework\Config\FileIterator))
>   3 /var/www/html/projectnenny/generated/code/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/Config/Reader/Dom/Proxy.php(95):
>   Magento\Framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem->read('global') #4
>   /var/www/html/projectnenny/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/C in
>   /var/www/html/projectnenny/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php on
>   line 164

---

Normally I use PHP 7.2 for Magento 2. Recently I received a complete
project in Magento that is not running in PHP 7.2, so I change my PHP version to 7.0 also. Install all required extensions in PHP 7.0
version

and when open my project Home page receiving this error.
after that also run all issue related commands like:-

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-dom
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-xml
```

but my problem is not solved.

Please help

Comment: What is the magento version of your new project

Answer (score 0):

In my case the dom extension was enabled twice. Once in the `dom.ini` and also in the `php.ini`. I removed the `extension=dom.so` entry from the php.ini and reloaded the apache2 webserver.